# Azure Mobile Services Javascript Library and Update - No method read

Tags: javascript, promise, azure-mobile-services

Taking the code examples from this [site](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/how-to-guides/work-with-html-js-client/#header-6).  The following boiled down code generates the following javascript error:  `TypeError: Object #<Promise> has no method 'read'`

Code:

```
Azure.notification = client.getTable('notification');

 var a = Azure.notification.update({
            id: id,
            isRead: true
        }).read().done(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }, function (err) {

        });
```

The referenced code from the link is almost identical.   The only difference that I can tell is that I'm holding a reference to several different tables in the `Azure` object and have had no issues querying the data, only with this update.  I am looking for how to determine if the update was successful or not.

```
todoItemTable.update({
       id: idToUpdate,
       text: newText
    }).read().done(function (result) {
       alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    }, function (err) {
       alert("Error: " + err);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research the following page which seems to be different uses `then` with the promise callback.

```
 todoItemTable.update({ id: getTodoItemId(this), complete: isComplete })
    .then(refreshTodoItems);
```

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-data-html/

I'm not sure if I'm too tired from working all weekend or there is an issue with the documentation.

Comment: That's an issue with the documentation, thanks for bringing it up. I'll follow up with the team to have it fixed. In the "insert" / "delete" and "update" sections, there should not be a "read()" in the sample code.

Comment: It doesn't work with the `done` either if I recall correctly.  I appreciate the followup.